# How to filter out messages with Winston v2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

`filters` modify the `message`, and `rewrites` modify the `meta`. 
Using winston v2^, What are my options if I want to filter out (not to print) certain messages?

Answer (score 1):

*I know the question asks for winston 2, but maybe winston 3 is more relevant since this thread is ~8 months old*

for winston 2, read https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/2.4.0/docs/transports.md#console-transport and figure it out, probably need to define a `formatter` as that's a prop in the options for that versions Console transport

figured it out by reading the source code for winston. It seems to depend on this module, logform.

```
const logform = require('logform');
// const { MESSAGE } = require('triple-beam'); // prop for info in winston formater to expose the shown message 

function filterMessagesFormat(filterFunc) {
  const formatFunc = (info) => {
    if (filterFunc(info.message)) return info;
    return null;
  };

  const format = logform.format(formatFunc);
  format.transform = formatFunc;

  return format;
}
```

usage is the same as their formats they define like json, colorize, simple, and others

in the options for `winston.createLogger(options)`, you define a prop called `transports` and you want one of the values of that array to be the output from this function like:

```
transports: [
  new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.combine(
      filterMessagesFormat((msg) => msg !== 'useless message'),
    ),
    handleExceptions: false,
  }),
```

my personal logger creator func https://gist.github.com/jtara1/3128cc6ed3dbea6d507b30967ab0e197 which shows a includes the change to allow a filter func to be used